# How can I link to a child route that targets a named outlet in Angular 2/4/5?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Here is an example of my code. What I am looking for is to simply make the Open Dialog work.

Oof. Very dumb of me to forget the link to the actual example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-gfmrjm

Comment: There’s no code in the question. Please resubmit. Probably you have to wrap it in code formatting in the rich editor because otherwise it’s sanitised and it won’t show

Comment: @HugoNoro Feeling super embarrassed here! Thanks for pointing that out! It has been updated with an example.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed. We’ve all been there. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re missing the path on the routerLink for the popup. Should it have the /private?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand. I'd prefer for it to be relative, so perhaps I need to do ./ something. It almost seems like I would have to rewrite any relative links any time the route changes.

From that perspective, it seems better to always create absolute links (so that it would become an absolute URL to the current page, without the popup route added). Unfortunately, a lot of this stuff just isn't clear to me from the docs.

Comment: So to try and understand the goal: are you trying to navigate away from the page? Or just opening content in a modal window?

Comment: The goal is for the Open Dialog link to open a modal on any of the pages that are linked: Home, Page2 or Page3. But the dialog should not be able to remain open on the page linked to by Public. Apologies again for the lack of detail in the question. I think I failed to consider the amount of information that was in my head vs in the post.